# About potassium bromate in bread

Tags: food-safety

Why is potassium bromate in bread banned in almost all countries of the world except for countries in Africa?

Comment: It is commonly used in commercial breads in the United States. Yes, it is NOT used in Brazil, Canada, China, most of Europe or the UK. Where did you get the information it is only used in Africa?

Comment: a brothel gallery banned throughout Europe and not only in some countries.two years ago was banned in even in India.in the United States of America were one of the last countries to ban it from being used as a bread improver.this is due to the fact that the alternative to potassium bromate is mainly produced by European companies and it is called enzymes.US companies started looking for markets in Africa.Potassium bromate is cheap and effective It has been shown to be carcinogenic.the use of potassium bromide is an unjustifiably high risk!

Answer (score 1):

Potassium bromate is used as a [flour improver in the US](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Potassium_bromate#Uses_in_baking) as it strengthens the dough and allows higher rising. It is an oxidizing agent, and under the right conditions, will be completely used up while baking bread.

It has been banned in the rest of the world because of its [potential for being a carcinogenic](http://www.inchem.org/documents/iarc/vol73/73-17.html) if used improperly.

Comment: safe alternatives to potassium bromate as bread improver affect flourish in the same way but without any risk.ascorbic acid known as vitamin C is also an oxidizer Flour but it does not hide any risk!there are practically no guarantees that it will be used properly in flour!the risk that in its use there is always the possibility of carcinogenic effects on the human body.even a percentage of risk is not acceptable when the stake is the health of people and nations!the strategy that is used in Europe is completely moral and acceptable- even in case of doubt, certain substances should be banned.

Comment: You seem to be an expert on this stuff @AleksandarSolunov Why don't you post an answer of your own?  (Just don't use the word "бордей" **;-)**